# Android Gradle build error "AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon."

Tags: android, gradle, aapt2

I got this error while trying to build an Android app:

> Execution failed for task ':admin:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade`
> `AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows` Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

Most other solutions I found were related to an image in the project being too large however, that didn't work for me as all my images had sizes below 50kb.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I found that this error occurs when additional modules are created in the project and linked to other app modules (using `implementation project`) but the plugin in the module's build.gradle file is set to `'com.android.application'` instead of `'com.android.library'`.

I found this solution in an answer to a different issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62104026/13800771).

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188096932

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: But that makes it a library not a module, right? From what I understand here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects this makes a difference.

Comment: According to that article, it's still a module, just now a _library_ module. 
However, considering that you can't really use code from an Android app module in another app module without running into the above error, I think it's right for it to be a library module.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar error when I tried upgrading the `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` versions to 34 (From 33).

What I had to do was to change my gradle plugin version from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

I don't know what exactly is the issue here yet. But I got the idea from the [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk). It does not specifically say to upgrade gradle plugin version but I sensed it from the section where they have mentioned about how to write `compileSdk` in AGP higher than `7.0.0` as compared to lower than `4.2.0`.

I was so confused as to what happens to the AGP versions in between. But I thought of upgrading a AGP to higher than `7.0.0` and it worked fine.

If someone gets a better explanation of why this is the case, please comment. Thanks

Comment: 4 years after, same problem, same solution, thanks

Answer (score 6):

when upgrading the target SDK version to 34, I also set the compile SDK version to the same 34. Then I changed it as below.

```
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 34
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer from user "Schnelldev" can be shortened: for the application, the plugin `'com.android.application'` should be used, and for each individual module `'com.android.library'`

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue was the compileSdkVersion.
it was set as:
compileSdkVersion 34
(like my target version).

I fixed the issue by setting it to 33:
compileSdkVersion 33

Answer (score 0):

In flutter 3.19 i update the build script dependencies to the following

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

> the second dependency line is not involved