# AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon. This should not happen under normal circumstances,

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aapt, aapt2

React Native version 63.5,

AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon. This should not happen under normal circumstances.

Even after undoing the changes and removing the aforementioned line, i am  still facing the same error repeatedly.I have attempted cleaning the project, rebuilding it, and also following the steps of "File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart" to clear the IDE's cache, but unfortunately, I haven't had any success in resolving the issue.

Please let me know if there's any additional information you can provide or if you have any specific questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Gradle build error "AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233807/android-gradle-build-error-aapt2-aapt2-4-1-0-6503028-windows-daemon-0-unexpec)