# Flutter App Migration to Android 14 , Getting Error while compilation

Tags: android, flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:processCommunicatorDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233807/android-gradle-build-error-aapt2-aapt2-4-1-0-6503028-windows-daemon-0-unexpec